# dotnet entity framework and mysql cluster

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, cluster-computing

After googling and stackoverflowing for a while, I still cannot find anything relevant to this topic.  As a newbie in MySQL cluster, I'm hoping someone has the experience to share the knowledge:

When programming using .net EF, will there be any difference between dealing with a normal mysql and with a mysql cluster? And what should be noticed when using EF upon a mysql cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no differences in dotnet client code between accessing a MySQL cluster and a non-clustered MySQL server. There are connection strings that can have comma-separated lists of host names or addresses, which will allow the connector to use one of several servers. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html